# Nodejs: how are written the libraries?

Tags: node.js

maybe the question is trivial, but I have no answer. With what language the nodejs libraries are written that we use with the keyword require?

Thank you!
Roberto

Comment: Depends. Mostly javascript (especially 3rd party libraries) but sometimes C.

Comment: For writing javascript modules: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html, for writing C++ modules: https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html